# How to to get all methods in a class and store in a file Using DXCore?

Tags: coderush, dxcore

I am trying to write a simple console application as a learner with Dxcore open Api's. I have parsed a C# file using the following line of code.

```
   LanguageElement   parsedFile = parser.ParseFile(fileLocation)
```

and i want to try few basic things on this file. So i was trying to get all methods in this file and its parameters and place them in a list.

I saw a property which would do this but could not use it.

```
  DevExpress.CodeRush.StructuralParser.TypeDeclaration.AllMethods
```

Also few links on Dxcore plugin development documentations would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast your "parserFile" reference to the SourceFile type instance and then use the code like this:

```
  SourceFile parsedFile = parser.ParseFile(fileLocation) as SourceFile;
  if (parsedFile != null)
    foreach (TypeDeclaration type in parsedFile.AllTypes)
      foreach (Method method in type.AllMethods)
        foreach (Param param in method.Parameters)
        {
          // Do something...
        }
```

This link may probably be a bit of help: [How to enumerate solution and source code items using DXCore](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/04/how-to-enumerate-solution-and-source-code-items-using-dxcore/)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the following code.

```
SourceFile parsedFile = CodeRush.Language.Parse(fileName);
foreach (TypeDeclaration type in parsedFile.AllTypes)
{
    foreach (Method method in type.AllMethods)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Note the change from **LanguageElement** to **SourceFile**.

Comment: Thank you Rory, 

SourceFile parsedFile = parser.ParseFile(filelocation) as SourceFile; worked as i had used   CSharp30Parser parser = new CSharp30Parser();. I dont know the namespace I have to import for CodeRush in SourceFile parsedFile = CodeRush.Language.Parse(fileName);.